# yii2 restful api: (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: reactjs, rest, yii2

I want use React with Yii2 RESTful, i created a users controller like this:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UsersController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

when open link in browser show my users, when i want use `axios` in react, i get error i browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/rest/web/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

but when i check `network` in firefox developer tools, i find axios request and it status in 200 and recievies the response correctly.

i try use `behaviors` function in my controllers, like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```

but get error

> Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException Response content
>   must not be an array.

how i can fix this?

Comment: so what is the current problem the exception of invalid argument?

Comment: React can't get rest response and get error 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked... '

Comment: After add behavior, i get Invalid Argument error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Updated the answer as the logic implemented was allowing every request to by pass the authentication filters (**Thanks to [`@KalyanHalderRaaz`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3180884/kalyan-halder-raaz) for pointing out the bug**).

There are two things to change

- When re-adding the filters it is better to specify which auth you are using. 
  change the code below

  ```
  // re-add authentication filter
  $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
  ```

  to the following, i am using `BasicAuth` for example.

  ```
  $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
      'class' => yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::class
  ];
  ```
- When adding a `beforeAction()` dont forget to wrap the logic in `if(parent::beforeAction($action))` otherwise it would authenticate every request as we are just returning `true` for every request here and also not calling the parent which would trigger the filters.

  Replace the `beforeAction()` with the following

  ```
  public function beforeAction($action)
  {
      if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
          \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
          return true;
      }

  }
  ```

Just make sure you are overriding the `findIdentityByAccessToken()` in the User identity model

---

According to [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#cors) you should first unset the `authenticator` filter in order to add the `Cors` filter, so your behavior should look like

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    // remove authentication filter necessary because we need to 
    // add CORS filter and it should be added after the CORS
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => '\yii\filters\Cors',
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
        ],
    ];

    // re-add authentication filter of your choce
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::class
    ];

    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

And you can set the response format to json inside your controller by adding the `beforeAction` like below

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution is working. But I noticed after this solution every url/method is accessible by option request. and its giving data like authenticated users. So give a security check.

Comment: @KalyanHalderRaaz , yes you were right this does allow and i updated the answer with the reason and fix , do update at your end

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution is to define a virtual host. I had a similar issue when I set the API URL as http://localhost:8080/ or http://127.0.0.1:8080/

By defining the virtual hosts in XAMMP and mapping it to 127.0.0.1, the issue is gone.