# How to call rest API of Yii2 in Angular 7

Tags: angular, yii2, cors, angular7, yii2-api

I have a Angular service which makes an API call. Here is my `subscribe.service.ts` file

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SubscribeService {
      readonly postURL = "http://localhost/sampleproject/frontend/web/api/subscribe";
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

      subscribeSubmit(subscriber){
       return this.http.post(this.postURL, subscriber);
      }
    }
```

The postURL which is called as an API is in yii2. Below is my `ApiController.php` file

```
            <?php
        namespace frontend\controllers;
        use Yii;
        use yii\web\Controller;

        class ApiController extends Controller {
            public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
            public static function allowedDomains() {
            return [
                 '*',                       
            ];
        }

            public function behaviors() {
            return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                'corsFilter'  => [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                    'cors'  => [
                        'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                        'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,       
                    ],
                ],

            ]);
        }

             public function beforeAction($action) {
                if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest &&
                    \Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== \yii\helpers\Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl) && Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'subscribeforangular') {
                    \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/../../login');
                }
                else {
                    return parent::beforeAction($action);
                }
            }

            public function actionSubscribe(){
                print_r($_POST);
            }

        }
```

I am trying to POST data from angular using http.post to the action `"subscribe"` which is in yii2, but I am getting the below error

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/sampleproject/frontend/web/api/subscribe' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The below lines are not getting added when I have checked in "Network" in console, which says that the CORS is not implemented with what I have written in controller.
As per my R&D the below lines have to be added in "http://localhost/sampleproject/frontend/web/api/subscribe"

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-site.example.com
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 09:21:47 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Content-Length: 27
    Connection: keep-alive
```

I have googled the solution and implemented them, but still I am getting the same error in all the cases.

Please help !! I am trying this since 2 days. I am unable to find a proper solution and hence posted here.

Comment: i dont have any experience of working with angular but with javascript and you need to provide the headers along with the request and you should configure properly configure the server side see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865764/using-cors-filter-to-block-ajax-requests) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807205/yii2-restful-api-reason-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing/53807306#53807306)