# Yii2 bug with CORS when not valid access token

Tags: rest, yii2, cors, request-headers

I did with yii2 an acess token authorization if the access token is valid it works fine, but if the access token is invalid it returns the following CORS problem

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'server' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

if the token is expired, the server works fine storing the old token on another table etc, but the client still gets the same CORS problem

I don't understand why it only happens when I try to return a 401 response, but it works when the acces token is valid, any idea?

This is the code I think its relevant
BehaviorsConfig.php

```
    public static function corsFilterConfig($metodos_aceptados)
{
    return [
        'class' => Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'], // Añadido
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => $metodos_aceptados,
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => false,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
        ],
    ];
}


public static function authenticatorConfig() 
{
    return [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['options'],
        'tokenParam' => 'access_token',
    ];
}
```

every controller

```
    public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = BehaviorsConfig::corsFilterConfig(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']);
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = BehaviorsConfig::authenticatorConfig();
    return $behaviors;
}
```

and now to check if the token is still valid and not expired I did this function

```
 public function beforeAction($action){
    if(AccessService::isExpired()){
        throw new HttpException(401, "Sesión expirada, vuelva a conectarse.");
    }
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you are not unsetting the `authenticator` before setting the `CORS` filter, you should unset and the apply the authenticator again see this post if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807205/yii2-restful-api-reason-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing/53807306#53807306

Comment: Sorry for the lack of an answer, seems the cause of the problem wasn't yii at all, htaccess problem    in case someone find the same problem check your htaccess!

Comment: you must be using altered settings and not the default one, as the frontend backnd and API all have the same `.htaccess` by default